# How to provide a callback for a click function?

Tags: jquery

I have this code where I need to do something with it after a class is added to it but the function sometimes run before the class is added causing issues.  I am trying to provide a callback AFTER the class is added, then run function.  I want to do this without using `setTimeout` if possible.

Here is a snippet of code:

```
$( '.item' ).on( 'click', '.add-class', function() {
     $( this ).parents( '.box' ).addClass( 'active' );

     runInit(); // sometimes run before above class is added
} );
```

Comment: That comment states something that is absolutely impossible, as javascript has only one thread, and the class would most certainly be added before the function runs, unless you have a magic browser.

Comment: Really? I thought completely different @adeneo.  I thought the OP is saying that the `runInit` function gets called outside of that `click` handler as well.  I could be completely off track :)

Comment: Have you tried setting a debugger breakpoint in `runInit()` and looking at the stack trace to see where it's called from when it's not supposed to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either check for `hasClass` (http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) in your `runInit()` function definition or trigger a new event after a class gets added like following:

```
$( '.item' ).on( 'click', '.add-class', function() {
     $( this ).parents( '.box' ).addClass( 'active' ).trigger('boxClassChanged');

     runInit(); // sometimes run before above class is added
} );

// Use your selector here in place of '.box'
$('.box').on('boxClassChanged', function() {
    runInit();
});
```

This second option is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: ah...thank you...completely forgot i can simply add a trigger event function...that is the best route instead of reverting to setTimeout which I had thought of but was against it...

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.item').on('click', '.add-class', function () {
    $(this).parents('.box').addClass('active');
    setTimeout(function () {
        runInit();
    }, 1);
});
```

Comment: This is not an answer in any way. The `parents` and the `addclass` methods are synchronous